# Is it possible to search all inbox like Gmail App on desktop computer?

Tags: gmail

Gmail App (at least for iOS) has a very cool feature: I can search across all my Gmail accounts in one place.

Is it possible to do it on the desktop?

Update: For "desktop", I mean the web app, since Gmail has never released a desktop native app.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate your OS and any email client you are using.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] and include what desktop email client are you using.

Comment: @User24601I have updated the question. Thanks